# how to properly format in for loop

Tags: java, loops, text, for-loop, format

I have a problem with a loop.
It formats text like this:

```
cat
 cats
  blablabla
   end
```

instead of this:

```
cat
   cats
       blablablabla
```

As shown in the screenshot, on each line I would like to add a number of spaces equal to the length of the words for all previous lines.

```
        int length=i+1
        int j;

        for(i=0; i<length; i++){    
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
              System.out.print(" ");
                  System.out.print(words[i]);
                  System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"add an additional loop for space with last word length"* - it is an incomprehensible thing.

Comment: this is neither a question, nor there are any Information to solve your "question"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++) {    
      for(j=0; j<i; j++)
         for(k = 0; k < words[j].length(); k++)
            System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.print(words[i]);
      System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void leftpad(int l, String s) {
   StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
   for(int j = 0; j < l; j++) b.append(" ");
   b.append(s);
   return b.toString();
}
public void printWTF() {
    int length = i + 1;
    int wl = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){              
          System.out.println(leftpad(wl, words[i]));
          wl += words[i].length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy task:

```
    String[] words = {"cat", "cats", "test"};
    int leftPaddding = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < leftPaddding; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        leftPaddding += words[i].length();
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
```

prints

```
cat
   cats
       test
```